# How to remove square brackets and anything between them with a regex?

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove text from between square brackets and the brackets themselves?

For example, I need:

```
hello [quote="im sneaky"] world
```

to become:

```
hello world
```

Here's what I'm trying to use, but it's not doing the trick:

```
preg_replace("/[\[(.)\]]/", '', $str);
```

I just ended up with:

```
hello quote="im sneaky" world
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters in a regex. They are used to list characters of a match. `[a-z]` matches any lowercase letter between `a` and `z`. `[03b]` matches a "0", "3", or "b". To match the characters `[` and `]`, you have to escape them with a preceding `\`.

Your code currently says "replace any character of `[]().` with an empty string" (reordered from the order in which you typed them for clarity).

---

Greedy match:

```
preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $str); // Replace from one [ to the last ]
```

A greedy match could match multiple [s and ]s. That expression would take `an example [of "sneaky"] text [with more "sneaky"] here` and turn it into `an example    here`.

Perl has a syntax for a non-greedy match (you most likely don't want to be greedy):

```
preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $str);
```

Non-greedy matches try to catch as few characters as possible. Using the same example: `an example [of "sneaky"] text [with more "sneaky"] here` becomes `an example  text  here`.

---

Only up to the first following ]:

```
preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '', $str); // Find a [, look for non-] characters, and then a ]
```

This is more explicit, but harder to read. Using the same example text, you'd get the output of the non-greedy expression.

---

Note that none of these deal explicitly with white space. The spaces on either side of `[` and `]` will remain.

Also note that all of these can fail for malformed input. Multiple `[`s and `]`s without matches could cause a surprising result.

Comment: Hmm, the malformed input is something I may run into. Is it possible to handle the instance of not having a matching ] ?

Comment: I'd have to know how you want it handled.  What would you hope for it to do with malformed input?

Comment: As a side note, if you're implementing a custom markup language, there are some really good complete alternatives that are much easier to drop in than doing it on your own from scratch.

Comment: For C#, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44314170/3873799

Answer (score 13):

Just in case you are looking for a recursive removal:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\[([^\[\]]++|(?R))*+\]/", "", $str);
```

That will convert this:

> This [text [more text]] is cool

to this:

> This is cool

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want parens for your outer brackets since it's a group.  square brackets are a range of expressions.  Not sure how to type it in SO.

```
/(\\[.*\\])/
```