# C# Use Regex to Remove everything inside brackets and the brackets themselves

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
var schoolName = "University of Hawaii [Maui/Oahu/Kaui]";
```

I would like to remove everything inside the brackets and the brackets themselves so the string outputs "University of Hawaii" only.

I have been looking for the correct regex but haven't found the solution for doing this:

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
var query = "University of Hawaii [Maui/Oahu/Kaui]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(query, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Will the bracketed text always be at the end of the string? If so, you could skip the regex all together and just do `query = query.Remove(query.LastIndexOf("["));` or perhaps `LastIndexOf(" ")` so that you get rid of the trailing space as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there. You have to use the Replace method:

```
var pattern = @" \[(.*?)\]";
var query = "University of Hawaii [Maui/Oahu/Kaui]";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(query, pattern, string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `\[.*?\]` you can match everything including the brackets.

As I am not very familiar with C#, could you then replace it with an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var pattern = @"\s\[.*\]";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var result = regex.Replace(query, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var pattern = @"\[.*\]";
var query = "University of Hawaii [Maui/Oahu/Kaui]";
var result = Regex.Replace(query, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code I am using to do the job :

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
var result = Regex.Replace(stringToSanitize, pattern, string.Empty);
```