# Regex_replace square brackets not working in SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, wordpress, replace, brackets

I would like to remove square brackets and content between them from WP posts. I found very [helpful topic for similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359921/how-to-remove-square-brackets-and-anything-between-them-with-a-regex), unfortunately when I am using this regex in SQL query, it's not working - not matches found.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'\[(.+?)\]','') WHERE ID = '4186' AND post_type = 'page';
```

I have tested sql and regex itself, separately - their are working correctly, could anyone point me out the issue?

Comment: Try  `'\[[^][]*]'` or - if you need to double backslashes - `'\\[[^][]*]'`

Comment: Unfortunately, #3696 - The regular expression contains an unclosed bracket expression.

Comment: Aha, so it is MySQL v.8+. You need `'\\[[^\\]\\[]*]'`

Comment: Basically, `'\\[(.+?)]'` should work, too.