# Woocommerce checkout terms and conditions - remove control commands and tags

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

The embedded T&C (terms and conditions) shown in the box on the checkout page of woocommerce do show the control commands or tags of the T&C page https://lonesome-dragon.com/terms_conditions/.

This looks quite messy in the text box during the checkout and I want to hide these control commands there.

Is this an issue of my theme (Qode Bridge with WP Bakery Builder) or can I maybe filter it out with a PHP snippet on the checkout page (perhaps this is possible since all these control commands are strings between brackets)?

Example of such control commands or tags (please also see the attached screenshot)

[/vc_column_text][vc_separator type=”transparent” up=”15″]

[Example how this looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSDGd.jpg)

The site (semi-SFW) where this happens is: https://lonesome-dragon.com/ (just put something from the shop in the cart, proceed to checkout and click on the words "terms and conditions" near the T&C checkbox to see these ugly tags.

Thanks a lot for your hints

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: How did you add this section to the page? Show your code

Comment: How did we add this section to the page? As far as I know, it's the standard woocommerce locig to pull the T&C page into a box in the Checkout page.

While the T&C page alone looks great, pulled into this box on the Checkout page will look bad, because these tags cannot be interpreted there and are shown as such. So I'm looking for a way to filter these tags out in the Checkout page if possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution how to get rid of these tags (removes everything between square brackets and the brackets as well).

Just for all other people who might  have the same issue, here is the code:

```
/*** Strip Shortcode from Terms & Conditions Box *****/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_terms_and_conditions_page_content', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_terms_and_conditions_page_content_custom', 30 );
function wc_terms_and_conditions_page_content_custom() {
    $terms_page_id = wc_terms_and_conditions_page_id();
    if ( ! $terms_page_id ) {
        return;
    }
    $page = get_post( $terms_page_id );
    if ( $page && 'publish' === $page->post_status && $page->post_content && ! has_shortcode( $page->post_content, 'woocommerce_checkout' )) {
/* hier bleiben tags mit "/" erhalten wie beispielsweise [vc_column width=”1/2″], weshalb das Pattern in preg_replace ersetzt wurde */
/* echo '<div class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions" style="display: none; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">' . wp_kses_post( wc_format_content(preg_replace( "~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $page->post_content ) ) ) . '</div>';} */
echo '<div class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions" style="display: none; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">' . wp_kses_post( wc_format_content(preg_replace( "/\[([^\[\]]++|(?R))*+\]/", '', $page->post_content ) ) ) . '</div>';}  
}
```

Source: https://xtemos.com/forums/topic/help-shortcodes-visible-in-terms-and-conditions/
and adjusted with insights from here:
[How to remove square brackets and anything between them with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359921/how-to-remove-square-brackets-and-anything-between-them-with-a-regex)